# Calc Question With Tangent Lines

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

Can someone help me with this calc problem:

$x^{\frac23}+y^{\frac23}=1$. Calculate the points where the tangent line has a slope of 1.

I know how to do it by finding the derivative but kept getting no solution, can anyone give me the right answer?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on [ask], on [formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and on writing down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).


Can you please [edit] your post and write your attempts at solving the problem? If your question is clear and focused on your specific difficulty and you show your effort in solving the problem, it's more likely to get good and helping answers.

Answer (score 0):

You should try implicit differentiation as follows: $\frac{d}{dx}(x^{\frac{2}{3}} + y^{\frac{2}{3}}) = \frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}} + \frac{2}{3}y^{-\frac{1}{3}}\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$.

Now express, $\frac{dy}{dx} = -x^{-\frac{1}{3}}y^{\frac{1}{3}}$ assuming $y\neq 0$. Then all points with slope of 1 will be precisely the ones in the set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:-x^{-\frac{1}{3}}y^{\frac{1}{3}} = 1\}$.

Comment: i tried that. what points did u get?

Comment: Do you need the concrete numeric examples? The points are all the ones in the set described above. This is an uncountable number of points from what I can tell.

Comment: No, there are only two. Remember that the points have to lie on the curve.

Comment: From what is here, you can conclude that if $\frac {dy}{dx} = 1 \implies y = -x$ plug that into the original equation and you get $2y^\frac 23 = 1$

Comment: So $y^{2/3}= \frac12 \implies y^2=\frac18 \implies y = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}$